# Recursive function not returning values in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am developing a budget app API where it allows users to enter their pay dates [1, 15] etc. It will be in list format, then have them have a "last paid date" 05/17/2020 for example. I want to return a list of PayPeriodModel objects that have a start date attribute and end date attribute. So a sample of what this would be is last_paid: datetime = 05/17/2020, pay_dates = [1,15]. There should be a list of PayPeriodModel objects that return: 
6/01/2020 - 6/14/2020
6/15/2020 - 6/30/2020
...etc

This is the code I have so far, and I am not sure why it does not work. If anyone has any ideas or even a different way to approach this problem let me know!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import json

from models.user import UserModel

class PayPeriodModel():
    def __init__(self, start: datetime, end: datetime):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.start} - {self.end}"
        #return f"Pay period starting {datetime.strftime(self.start, '%m/%d/%Y')} and ending {datetime.strftime(self.end, '%m/%d/%Y')}"

    def start_day(self):
        return datetime.strptime(self.start, '%d')

    def end_day(self):
        return datetime.strptime(self.end, '%d')

    @classmethod
    def get_pay_periods(self, user: UserModel, count):
        pay_periods = []

        def find_pay_periods_with_pay_dates(start_date: datetime, dates: list, count: int):
            # Take month and year of start_date for testing against the list of dates
            m = start_date.month
            y = start_date.year
            # if we have to add to a month and its 13, then we need to add a year
            new_month = False

            # Test against the dates of the pay_dates list to see if either one is next
            for date in dates:
                test_date = datetime(y, m, date)
                if test_date > start_date:
                    if count == 0:
                        return test_date - timedelta(days=1)
                    pp = PayPeriodModel(test_date, find_pay_periods_with_pay_dates(test_date, dates, count-1))
                    pay_periods.append(pp)
                # If we exhausted our list, then we must need a new month
                elif date == dates[-1]:
                    new_month = True

            if new_month == True:
                new_month = m+1
                new_year = y+1 if new_month == 13 else 0
                new_month = 1 if new_month == 13 else new_month
                test_date = datetime(y, m, dates[0]) + relativedelta(month=new_month, year=new_year)
                if count == 0:
                    return test_date - timedelta(days=1)
                pp = PayPeriodModel(test_date, find_pay_periods_with_pay_dates(test_date, dates, count-1))
                pay_periods.append(pp)

        find_pay_periods_with_pay_dates(user.last_pay_date, json.loads(user.pay_dates), count)

        return pay_periods
```

This keeps giving me:

```
2020-07-15 00:00:00 - 2020-7-31
2020-07-01 00:00:00 - None
2020-06-15 00:00:00 - None
2020-06-01 00:00:00 - None
```

Comment: Is there a reason why this is a class method? It doesn't seem to use anything in the class.

Comment: `find_pay_periods_with_pay_dates()` doesn't return anything unless `new_month == True` and `count == 0`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code you provided doesn't actually call anything, just defines a class. As well it's a lot of code.

Comment: And much of that code is irrelevant to the problem.